# keytool not working in Ubuntu: incorrect magic

Tags: java, linux, ubuntu, certificate, keytool

I am with Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. When I am in

```
$JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security
```

and want to list the certificates in `cacerts`, with these commands:

```
keytool -list -keystore cacerts
```

it prompts me for password, so I enter the default password:

```
changeit
```

and an exception occurs:

```
keytool error: gnu.javax.crypto.keyring.MalformedKeyringException: incorrect magic
```

Why it this happenning?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If this happens, you can try this to find out more about what `keytool` really represents.

```
keytool -version
```

if it gives you output like this:

```
Unrecognized command: -version
Usage:  keytool [COMMAND] [-- COMMAND]...
Manage private keys and public certificates.

Available commands:
....
```

Try this:

```
update-alternatives --display keytool
```

And if you have seen this:

```
keytool - AUTO
link best version is /usr/bin/gkeytool-5
link points to /usr/bin/gkeytool-5
link keytool is /usr/bin/keytool
slave keytool.1.gz is /usr/share/man/man1/keytool.1.gz
/usr/bin/gkeytool-5 - priority 1050
secondary keytool.1.gz：/usr/share/man/man1/gkeytool-5.1.gz
```

Now you know that the `keytool` is actually not pointing to `$JAVA_HOME/bin/keytool`, but to something similar but different, that is native of Ubuntu, named `gkeytool`, which offers the same functionalities but will fail at this specific case.

So, you can:

1. To not eliminate the `gkeytool`, use `update-alternatives` to change the keyword `keytool`, to make it point to `$JAVA_HOME/bin/keytool`, which should be at priority level 0. Use `update-alternatives -help` to see full syntax.
2. Or, you can access the real `keytool` offered by JDK, by:

   `cd $JAVA_HOME/bin/`
   And, 
    `./keytool -list -keystore <full/path/to/cacerts>`

Note the `./` part is crucial.

Of course, before using the system variable `$JAVA_HOME`, you have to set it. First, look for it in the existent variables by

```
env | grep -i java_home
```

`-i` means "case insensitive".

if it returns nothing, then

```
export JAVA_HOME=<path/to/your/jdk/installation/directory/>
```

(`export` only sets session-wide environment variables. Once closed this Terminal, values set here is not working any more. For setting

- this-user-only,
- user-wide except `su`,
- user-wide including `su`,
- system-wide-and-shell-only,
- system-wide-for-all-applications, and
- system-wide for locale variables,

be sure to read this link: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables)